# How much higher is muon flux at Earth's poles?

Tags: magnetic-fields, geophysics, cosmic-rays

https://futurism.com/make-a-cosmic-ray-detector-at-home-and-test-relativity-2

This article states that the Earth's magnetic field funnels incoming muons towards the magnetic poles. Quantitatively, how large is this effect? By what factor is cosmic ray flux (and, unless I'm missing something, muon flux) greater at the poles than at, say, the latitudes in the USA?

Comment: https://cds.cern.ch/record/427778/files/0002052.pdf is a starting point, although that shows Kiel vs the equator.

Comment: that futurismism article seems to not understand the difference between the solar wind and cosmic rays.

Comment: It depends on the energy of the particles, does it not?  A muon with an EeV of energy probably doesn't care too much about Earth's magnetic field where one down at a GeV may care a little bit (still not much)...